# Mongo change stream in scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

Reading the documentation of `mongo-scala-driver_2.12` more specifically the doc for [MongoCollection](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.2/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/MongoCollection.html) I thought that I should be able to connect to a mongo change stream doing the following

```
val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("MyCollection")
    collection.watch().subscribe(
      (doc: Document) => println(doc.toJson),
      (t: Throwable) => // handle failure,
      () => // handle this case too 
)
```

However I get a compilation error saying that `watch()` is not a member of collection.

In the documentation the method is described as

```
def watch[C]()(implicit e: DefaultsTo[C, TResult], ct: ClassTag[C]): ChangeStreamObservable[C]
```

Is this a problem with the documentation? I had similar problems while going trough the [quick tour](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.1/getting-started/quick-tour/) with

```
collection.find().first().printHeadResult()
```

This line would not compile saying that `printHeadResult` was not a member.

As a side node I can connect to a mongodb change stream in python but we want to take advantage of the multithreading capabilities of scala.

I am using scala version 2.12.6 and version 2.1.0 of `mongo-scala-driver_2.12`.

A minimal example yielding this compilation error is

```
import org.mongodb.scala._

/**
 * @author ${user.name}
 */
object App {

  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("connection-string")

    val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("db")

    val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("MyCollection")
    collection.watch().subscribe(
      (doc: Document) => println(doc.toJson),
      (t: Throwable) => // handle failure,
      () => println("done"))
  }
}
```

The whole stacktrace is

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.company:scala >----------------------
[INFO] Building scala 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory scala/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ scala ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.3.2:compile (default) @ scala ---
[INFO] scala/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 1 source files to scala/target/classes at 1530296517564
[ERROR] scala/src/main/scala/com/company/App.scala:21: error: value watch is not a member of org.mongodb.scala.MongoCollection[org.mongodb.scala.Document]
[ERROR]     collection.watch().subscribe(
[ERROR]                ^
[ERROR] one error found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.125 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-29T11:21:59-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.3.2:compile (default) on project scala_tutorial: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: YANNICKSSE did your change stream method worked? I tried with your code but I have an overloaded method issue on subscribe(), can you provide your solution please?

Comment: The solution below worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provided a link to the [2.2](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.2/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/MongoCollection.html) version of `MongoCollection`, which does have the `watch` method, but you're using version [2.1](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.1/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/MongoCollection.html), which does not have a `watch` method. Use the 2.2 version (or later; the current version is 2.4) of the Mongo Scala driver.

As for the error you're seeing when following the Quick Tour in the documentation, the `printHeadResult` method is implicitly provided in a [`Helpers.scala`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/r2.2.0/examples/src/test/scala/tour/Helpers.scala) class. The end of the [Quick Tour Primer](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.2/getting-started/quick-tour-primer/) page describes this helper class. You need to import those implicits if you want to use them.

Comment: I got confused with all these versions and now I also see the mention about `Helpers.scala`.